Parametric equations of the normal to a curve $\gamma(t)$ at a point $\gamma(t_0)$
Suppose we have some curve $\gamma$ which can be parametrized with time parameter $t\in(a,b)$. Let's take $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ for simplicity. We are restricted to $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ class curves.
At a point on the curve, say, $\gamma(t_0)$, the unit tangent vector could be defined as $(x'(t_0),y'(t_0))$. Then, I understand that the principal unit normal vector would obviously be $n(t_0)=(-y'(t_0),x'(t_0))$. The normal $n_{t_0}$ can be given by the following equation. $$n_{t_0}(\tau)=\gamma(t_0)+\tau \textbf{n}(t_0)$$
Can anyone explain whether there is a significance to $\tau$, and how this formula is derived? I am a beginner to this topic, so lucidity would be much appreciated.
Please point out if there are any corrections in my question above.

First, you have to assume your parametrization is regular, i.e., has nowhere-vanishing derivative. Second, you’re parametrizing the normal line, and $\tau$ is the parameter that moves you along that line.
